# How do I make an auto-retry system with labels?

Tags: java, goto

I would like to create an auto-retry system in my application. Here, I have my 3 nested for loops and in the last one, I have my try-catch, preceded by a label :

```
for (String engine : engines)
    for (String website : websites)
        for (String keyword : keywords)
        {
            scrape:
            try
            {
                // my long code
            }
            catch (Throwable t)
            {
            }
        }
```

And in that catch, I would have my auto-retry system :

```
catch (Throwable t)
{
    if (retry <= retries)
    {
        retry++;
        break scrape; // Go to the label
    }
}
```

The problem is that `break scrape` goes to the label but by skipping an iteration in my loop. Noting that I have 3 nested loops (might not be that important though), how would I proceed to go to that label without skipping a whole iteration?

Comment: Is it a school task or a work task? I mean, can you reuse an existing library, for example, Resilience4j or similar?

Comment: Why labels? Use a simple loop!

Comment: My code is long so just copy-pasting it would make my code much longer and less efficient.

Comment: _"`break scrape` goes to the label but by skipping an iteration in my loop"_ ... I cannot see your loop, but would `continue scrape;` help in your case? Otherwise you'll need to add a loop and/or add the `(retry <= retries)` as a loop condition.

Comment: I cannot use `continue scrape;` because it's not a loop label, it's a label on a try-catch.

Comment: I see. In that case, indeed a `while (retry < retries) { ... }` or a dedicated 3rd party library like [Failsafe](https://jodah.net/failsafe/retry/) or [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry) would help.